# How to fetch a file endpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I got an endpoint that directly returns an image file. This one is confusing me a bit cause i shouldnt fetch it as a normal json since its not returning json but the image itself. How can i display the file in my application?

My Code:

```
export const Comp = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});
  const url = `https://thingproxy.freeboard.io/fetch/https://exampleendpoint&dimension=small`;
   
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  },[]);

  const getData = async () => {
    const a = await fetch(url, { method: "GET", headers: headers });

   //Im not sure if im supposed to await a json, since the api is not returning a json but a file
   const response = await a.json();
     setState(response);
  };
 
  return (
    <div>
     
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: `await a.text()` or some other data format that is more suitable ... `.json()` is just one format available - documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Body_Interface_Methods) ... `.blob` or `.arrayBuffer` are also good candidates if the "file" is not just text (i.e. binary data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const Comp = () => {
   const [state, setState] = useState("");
   const url = `https://thingproxy.freeboard.io/fetch/https://exampleendpoint&dimension=small`;
   
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const getData = async () => {
    const a = await fetch(url, { method: "GET", headers: headers });
    //Im not sure if im supposed to await a json, since the api is not returning a json but a file
    const img = await a.arrayBuffer();
    const response = `data:${a.headers.get('Content-Type')};base64,${new Buffer(img).toString(
  "base64"
)}`;
    console.log(response);
    setState(response);
  };
  return <img src={state} alt="" />;
}
```

Here's a my solution codepen https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-meadow-ds4sk?file=/src/App.js:676-791

Answer (score 0):

If your file is stored at a static location on the server, you can crate an `img` element and set the `src`:

```
<img src={url} alt="this is my image" />
```

If the `url` is not static, try to fetch the url instead of the image itself.